# What is the equivalent lambda expression for System.out::println

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

I stumbled upon the following Java code which is using a method reference for `System.out.println`:

```
class SomeClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
           numbers.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }
}
```

What is the equivalent lambda expression for `System.out::println`?

Comment: It is not exactly functional though :-)

Comment: @StephenC can u plz suggest why?

Comment: Well `println` is hardly a side-effect free function ... is it.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The method reference `System.out::println` will evaluate `System.out` first, then create the equivalent of a lambda expression which *captures* the evaluated value. Usually, you would use
`o -> System.out.println(o)` to achieve the same as the method reference, but this lambda expression will evaluate `System.out` each time the method will be called.

So an *exact* equivalent would be:

```
PrintStream p = Objects.requireNonNull(System.out);
numbers.forEach(o -> p.println(o));
```

which will make a difference if someone invokes `System.setOut(…);` in-between.

Comment: I do understand that invocation target of a method reference is evaluated `when its declaration is first encountered`, that is logical to me. But is there a jls part that explicitly says this(I've really tried to find it... ). If invocation target is a method, one could capture the method and `this` for example, not the actual object that the method returns... as far as I understand. Or did I get that entirely wrong?

Comment: never mind... `First, if the method reference expression begins with an ExpressionName or a Primary, this subexpression is evaluated`

Comment: This comes under bound type method reference and the same is explained in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7qXfoZIqi2Q at time line 17:20.

Answer (score 6):

It's :

```
numbers.forEach(i -> {System.out.println(i);});
```

or even simpler :

```
numbers.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
```