# How to check if exists any duplicate in Java 8 Streams?

Tags: java, java-8, duplicates, java-stream

In java 8, what's the best way to check if a List contains any duplicate?

My idea was something like:

```
list.size() != list.stream().distinct().count()
```

Is it the best way?

Comment: if you are not interested in knowing what are those duplicates , then it's the best way !!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Your code would need to iterate over all elements. If you want to make sure that there are no duplicates simple method like

```
public static <T> boolean areAllUnique(List<T> list){
    Set<T> set = new HashSet<>();

    for (T t: list){
        if (!set.add(t))
            return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

would be more efficient since it can give you `false` immediately when first non-unique element would be found.

This method could also be rewritten using [`Stream#allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) which also is short-circuit (returns false immediately for first element which doesn't fulfill provided condition)
(assuming non-parallel streams and thread-safe environment)

```
public static <T> boolean areAllUnique(List<T> list){
    Set<T> set = new HashSet<>();
    return list.stream().allMatch(t -> set.add(t));
}
```

which can be farther shortened as [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) [pointed out in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053487/how-to-check-if-exists-any-duplicate-in-java-8-streams/30053822#comment48222350_30053822)

```
public static <T> boolean areAllUnique(List<T> list){
    return list.stream().allMatch(new HashSet<>()::add);
}
```

Comment: This can be even a one-liner: `return list.stream().allMatch(new HashSet<>()::add);`

Comment: @Holger Wow, I never though about that. Every day I learn something new :) Thanks!

Comment: Seems a bit dangerous to use a predicate with side effects here.

Comment: @StuartMarks Can you say something more about this subject? Are you referring to both `allMatch` solutions or only `allMatch(new HashSet<>()::add)`?

Comment: Both. The spec requires the predicate to be stateless. The usual caveat about running in parallel applies. ConcurrentHashMap might help. There may be other issues but I haven't had coffee yet. :-)

Comment: Yes, concurrency can make life harder. My answer is based on big assumption that it will be used by single thread without parallel stream, just like shown in first code example. This means that list will also not change while iterating.

Comment: @Stuart Marks: I think, for a one liner which spans the entire life cycle of the `Stream`, it’s acceptable to rely on the programmer to recognize whether that stream use is multi-threaded or not. Of course, if in doubt, using a `ConcurrentMap` might help. And a stateful predicate might not be the best thing, but is sometimes unavoidable, distinct tests being *the* common example. Maybe you remember [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27872852/2711488) ;^)

Comment: @Holger Of course I remember. :-) But using a stateful predicate requires a certain amount of caution. I think it's likely that somebody will copy and paste this code into a different context, without understanding its restrictions, and introduce bugs that way.

Comment: Perhaps a brief note is due in the answer regarding @StuartMarks' concern.

Comment: thank you all. just for some context, I was thinking just in a simple case, no concurrency problems :)

Comment: @Holger, @Pshemo, @StuartMarks, why not change to `stream.seguential().allMatch(new HashSet<>()::add);`? Will it be always correct? And I guess no overhead?

Comment: whats wrong with return list.size() == new HashSet<>(list).size(); as suggested by @Sasha?

Comment: @MubasharAhmad It is not that it is *wrong*, but `new HashSet<>(list)` will iterate over entire `list`, while `.allMatch(new HashSet<>()::add)` is short-circuit, it will return `false` at first occurrence of duplicate element.

Comment: @Pshemo: Thanks this was the answer I was looking for

Comment: by the way what if someone is looking for the inverse version of it e.g. it should return true if any value is duplicate?  one way is to use the above with not sign at the start but should I try anyMatch function. Just curious

Comment: Using Set and `anyMatch` would mean Predicate should return `false` for every *successful* adding to set and true otherwise. So we can't use nice `new HashSet<>()::add` if we want to add negation there (unless we will explicitly cast it to `Predicate<T>` to be able to use `negate()` method like `list.stream().anyMatch(((Predicate<T>) new HashSet<>()::add).negate())`. Without it we would need to create `Set` before stream and use lambda like `list.stream().anyMatch(elem -> !set.add(elem))`.

Comment: If the list is sorted, you only have to look at two items next to each other, not the whole result.

Comment: @Holger Can you help me understand how the one-liner works? I can see how it would work if we had a `final HashSet` the predicate refers, but how come the elements are being added to the same HashSet with the current way?

Comment: Instead of `list.stream().allMatch(t -> set.add(t));` you can also do `list.stream().allMatch(set::add))`

Comment: @KorayTugay a method reference of the form `expression::name` will evaluate `expression` and capture its result when the instance of the functional interface (here, a `Predicate`) is created and then reused throughout the entire lifetime of that object. See [What is the equivalent lambda expression for System.out::println](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28023364/2711488) or [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37979731/2711488)…

Comment: Btw if List is empty it will return "true" which is not correct....

Comment: @arxakoulini Hello. Regarding "*if List is empty it will return "true" which is not correct....*" could you clarify what makes you think that such result is not correct? Anyway this may interest you: [Why does Stream.allMatch() return true for an empty stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30223079)

Comment: Ok didn't know that, thanks for sharing. I assumed that allMatch in empty List should return false, so it's important to highlight that it isn't the case.

Comment: The `allMatch` solution isn't guaranteed to work (though it might for current stream implementations), since the API [makes no guarantees](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65915854/1108305) that sequential streams will perform all operations in the same thread (though current implementations might), and `HashSet.add` is not thread safe.

Comment: @M.Justin True, that is why before that part in answer there is clause "(assuming non-parallel streams and thread-safe environment)"

Answer (score 21):

Out of the three following one-liners

1. `return list.size() == new HashSet<>(list).size();`
2. `return list.size() == list.stream().distinct().count();`
3. `return list.stream().allMatch(ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()::add);`

the last one (#3) has the following benefits:

- Performance: it short-circuits, i.e. it stops on the first duplicate (while #1 and #2 always iterate till the end) – as Pshemo [commented](/q/30053487#comment81961406_30053822).
- Versatility: it allows to handle not only collections (e.g. lists), but also streams (without explicitly collecting them).

<sub>Additional notes:

 • [`ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()` is a way to create a concurrent hash set](/q/6992608).

 • Previous version of this answer suggested the following code: `return list.stream().sequential().allMatch(new HashSet<>()::add);` — but, as M. Justin [commented](/q/30053487#comment137947083_40977178), calling `BaseStream#sequential()` doesn't guarantee that the operations will be executed from the same thread and doesn't eliminate the need for synchronization.

 • Performance benefit from short-circuiting won't usually matter, because we typically use such code in assertions and other correctness checks, where items are *expected* to be unique; in contexts where duplicates are really a possibility, we typically not only check for their presence but also to find and handle them.

 • M. Justin's provides a [clean (not using side-effects) short-circuiting solution for Java 22](/a/78169084), but that's not a one-liner.</sub>

Comment: #3 operates via side effects, which is [potentially problematic](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects) with streams.  Additionally, the API [makes no guarantees](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65915854/1108305) that sequential streams will perform all operations in the same thread (though current implementations might), and `HashSet.add` is not thread safe.

Comment: @M.Justin, thanks. I assume you're right (though I'm not expert in that; and, personally for me, appearing of an “unusual” implementation in future looks as probable as narrowing of the specification in future; but, of course, it's anyway better for the code to be theoretically correct, not just practically working). I've tried to correct the answer.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the counting collector.

```
Stream.of(1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5, 6)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream().anyMatch(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Given array arr,

```
arr.length != Arrays.stream(arr).distinct().count()
```

will help check for duplicates

Comment: The question was not about arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Started this class as a StreamTool, but I think there must be an even better way with reduce or similar:

```java
public class StreamTool {

    /**
     * Whether stream records are unique in that stream.
     * @param <T> Type of records
     * @param records
     * @return true if there are no duplicates, false otherwise
     */
    public static <T> boolean isUnique(Stream<T> records) {
        return records.allMatch(new HashSet<>()::add);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short-circuiting solution that uses a custom gatherer, using the [JEP 461: Stream Gatherers](https://openjdk.org/jeps/461) Java 22 preview language feature:

```java
List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 1);

// A parallel stream must be used until JDK-8328316 is fixed
boolean hasDuplicate =
        list.stream().parallel().gather(hasDuplicate()).findAny().orElseThrow();
```

```java
static <T> Gatherer<T, ?, Boolean> hasDuplicate() {
    class State {
        boolean hasDuplicate = false;
        final Set<T> elements = new HashSet<>();
    }

    Gatherer.Integrator<State, T, Boolean> integrator =
            (state, element, downstream) -> {
                if (state.elements.add(element)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    state.hasDuplicate = true;
                    return false;
                }
            };
    return Gatherer.ofSequential(
            State::new,
            integrator,
            (state, downstream) -> downstream.push(state.hasDuplicate)
    );
}
```

This custom gatherer produces a stream with a single `Boolean` element indicating whether a duplicate was found.  It keeps track of each element encountered in a `Set`, and whether a duplicate has been found as a `boolean`.  It short circuits immediately with `true` when a duplicate element is encountered, or returns `false` if the end of the stream is reached without encountering any duplicates.

Note that this doesn't work on sequential streams in Java 22 due to [JDK-8328316](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=JDK-8328316), but it does work in Java 23 starting with b16.

This gatherer can be made parallel (at the cost of some increased complexity) by adding a combiner which can merge two states together, e.g.:

```java
BinaryOperator<State> combiner = (s1, s2) -> {
    if (s1.hasDuplicate || s2.hasDuplicate) {
        s1.elements.clear(); // No further need to keep these in memory
        s1.hasDuplicate = true;
    } else {
        int totalSize = s1.elements.size() + s2.elements.size();
        s1.elements.addAll(s2.elements);
        s1.hasDuplicate = s1.elements.size() != totalSize;
    }
    return s1;
};
return Gatherer.of(
        State::new,
        integrator,
        combiner,
        (state, downstream) -> downstream.push(state.hasDuplicate)
);
```

[`Gatherer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html):

> An intermediate operation that transforms a stream of input elements into a stream of output elements, optionally applying a final action when the end of the upstream is reached. […]
>
> […]
>
> There are many examples of gathering operations, including but not limited to: grouping elements into batches (windowing functions); de-duplicating consecutively similar elements; incremental accumulation functions (prefix scan); incremental reordering functions, etc. The class [`Gatherers`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html) provides implementations of common gathering operations.
>
> **API Note:**
>
> A `Gatherer` is specified by four functions that work together to process input elements, optionally using intermediate state, and optionally perform a final action at the end of input. They are:
>
> - creating a new, potentially mutable, state ([`initializer()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#initializer()))
> - integrating a new input element ([`integrator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#integrator()))
> - combining two states into one ([`combiner()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#combiner()))
> - performing an optional final action ([`finisher()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#finisher()))

[`Stream.gather(Gatherer<? super T,?,R> gatherer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)):

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given gatherer to the elements of this stream.

[`Gatherer.ofSequential(initializer, integrator, finisher)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#ofSequential(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Gatherer.Integrator,java.util.function.BiConsumer))

> Returns a new, sequential, `Gatherer` described by the given `initializer`, `integrator`, `combiner`, and `finisher`.

[`Gatherer.of(initializer, integrator, combiner, finisher)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#of(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Gatherer.Integrator,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.BiConsumer))

> Returns a new, sequential, `Gatherer` described by the given `initializer`, `integrator`, and `finisher`.

Comment: The finisher is invoked even if the integrator short-circuits, so you'll always get `false` emitted.

I'd probably define a `duplicates`-Gatherer like so:

```
static <T> Gatherer<T, ?, T> duplicates() {
    return Gatherer.ofSequential(
            HashSet::new,
            (state, element, downstream) -> state.add(element) || downstream.push(element)
    );
}
```

And then do:

```
var hasDuplicates = stream.gather(duplicates).findFirst().isPresent();
```

Comment: @ViktorKlang You're right that it needs to be fixed, but it does currently work as I've coded it in Java 22 due to a bug in the JDK gatherer code: [JDK-8328316](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=JDK-8328316). I'll get a fixed version up shortly.

Comment: @ViktorKlang I've updated my solution to only emit a single element, though it does not (yet) work for sequential streams due to [JDK-8328316](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=JDK-8328316).

Comment: An alternative solution that apparently does work in Java 22 is to use a `Collector` (but not `Stream.toList`): `list.stream().gather(hasDuplicate()).collect(Collectors.toList()).getFirst()`.

Answer (score -1):

Use `set.add()` it is faster.

```
Set<T> items = new HashSet<>();
list.stream().filter(n -> !items.add(n)) 
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: What is the point of creating two Set objects (one via `new HashSet` and other via `Collections.toSet()`? Also above code could be reduce to `new HashSet<>(list)`, *but* question is **not** about *removing* duplicates, it is about checking if duplicate elements *exist*.