# In R why does all(numeric(0)) give TRUE whereas any(numeric(0)) gives FALSE?

Tags: r

I was trying to generate a sequence of indices where consecutive 1s appear in a vector and I stumbled upon this peculiar case. Why peculiar, because I don't understand when `all()` gives TRUE it means every value is TRUE so `any()` should also give TRUE which is not the case here.

```
all(numeric(0))
# [1] TRUE
any(numeric(0))
# [1] FALSE
```

Most questions I found concern comparing numeric(0) to a number and how to avoid generating numeric(0)

Comment: See the "Note" section in `?all` for some info about this.

Comment: @Marius Both documentations claim that zero length vectors are ignored.  So this is not an explanation AFAIAC.

Comment: In R 3.5.0 `?all` includes a section that specifically discusses `all(logical(0))`. And the wording is somewhat confusing, "zero or more logical vectors. Other objects of zero length are ignored" could imply that only non-vector objects with length 0 are ignored.

Comment: @Marius Again, running `?any` shows the same language.  I think we would need to see the source code to answer this.

Comment: @Marius "Note" section in ?all only speaks about all and there is nothing in "Note" section of ?any. My question is not about why they give such output, instead about the confusion that outputs are not consistent.

Comment: @Marius I actually asked about all(numeric(0)) which is nowhere mentioned in the ?all. Does R see numeric(0) and logical(0) differently?

Comment: `numeric(0)` would be coerced to `logical(0)` first, so they should be treated the same. I should also mention that I didn't intend the details in `?all` to be treated as an answer to the question, just a starting point - hence posting as a comment.

Comment: `?all` states that "The value returned is TRUE[...] (including if there are no values)". `?any` states that "The value returned is [...] FALSE [...] (including if there are no values)." That's how the functions are defined. As to _why_ they're defined that way. I'd assume it ensures that other operations in R work as expected.

Comment: @neilfws agree this is the answer and the _why_ is given in the note on `?all()`: This convention ensures that `all(all(x), all(y)) == all(x, y)`

Comment: [Related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30223079/why-does-stream-allmatch-return-true-for-an-empty-stream)

Answer (score 5):

Since there are a couple of votes for my comment as an answer, I'll post it here.

The documentation `?all` states that (just showing the relevant parts):

> The value returned is TRUE [...] (including if there are no values)

And for `?any`, again just the relevant parts:

> The value returned is [...] FALSE [...] (including if there are no values)

The functions are defined that way so as other operations works as expected. In particular as @bmrn points out: `all(all(x), all(y)) == all(x, y)`.

Answer (score 2):

A similar phenomena occurs with `min` and `max`:

```
> min(numeric(0))
[1] Inf
#but
> max(numeric(0))
[1] -Inf
```

These two computations trigger warnings but not errors. The important question is why they return the values that they return. To answer that, note that another name for the minimum of a finite set is its *greatest lowest bound*. Everything is a lowest bound for an empty set, so no finite number is the greatest lowest bound, hence it is defined to be infinity. Dual reasoning applies to the maximum, since it is the *least upper bound*.

In the sense of [lattice theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)), the only reasonable definition for the join (least upper bound) of the empty set is to be the bottom element of the lattice and the meet (greatest lower bound) to be the top of the lattice. In the case of the extended real numbers, these top and bottom elements are `Inf` and `-Inf`.

The relationship between this and `any` and `all` is fairly straightforward: `all` is essentially `min` applied to truth values. It is a meet operator which when applied to the empty set should give you the top of the lattice, which is `TRUE` in the lattice of truth values. Similarly, `any` is basically `max` applied to truth values. It is a join operator which should when applied to the empty set give the bottom element of the lattice, which is `FALSE`.