# Why does `and` return True for empty foldable but `or` return False in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Is there a reason that would explain whether such results are to be expected? Are they better than being undefined?

```
>>> any (const True) []
False

>>> any (const False) []
False

>>> or []
False

>>> and []
True
```

I don't really understand what the Report is trying to say:

```
-- and returns the conjunction of a Boolean list. For the result to be
-- True, the list must be finite; False, however, results from a False
-- value at a finite index of a finite or infinite list. or is the
-- disjunctive dual of and. 
and, or     :: [Bool]    -> Bool
and         =  foldr    (&&)    True
or          =  foldr    (||)    False
```

Comment: Well `and` is basically making a `fold` with `&&` for all elements, but one needs initially `True` (since otherwise the result is always `False`, regardless of the values).

Comment: This is pretty standard handling across languages. For example, [here's the same question in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30223079/why-does-stream-allmatch-return-true-for-an-empty-stream). The concept is known as "vacuous truth".

Comment: Note that, for the same reason, `sum [] == 0` and `product [] == 1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To expand on the answer by Dan, the conjunction of an empty list of truth values being true `True` allows you to extend the expected properties of conjunction to that case.

For instance, we would expect that,

```
and (xs ++ ys) = (and xs) && (and ys)
```

and for all `xs` we have, `xs = xs ++ []` so,

```
  and xs 
= and (xs ++ [])
= (and xs) && (and [])
```

considering that `and xs` might be `True` or `False` it follows that,

```
True  = True  && (and [])
False = False && (and [])
```

Therefore we must have that `and []` is `True`.

Answer (score 8):

This is true of most languages with comparable functions. It is because "True" is the identity of "&&" (meaning x && True == x). Likewise, "False" is the identity of "||" (meaning x || False == x).