# Why is the behaviour of anyMatch different from that of allMatch and noneMatch for an empty Stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

While `Stream#anyMatch` returns `false` for an empty stream, `Stream#allMatch` and `Stream#noneMatch` return `true` for an empty stream.

Why is the behaviour of `anyMatch` different from that of `allMatch` and `noneMatch` for an empty Stream?

Comment: [Why does Stream.allMatch() return true for an empty stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30223079/2711488)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Stream#anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) evaluates the [existential quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification) of the predicate over the elements of the stream. The existential quantification always evaluates to `false` for an [empty set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification#The_empty_set).

On the other hand, [`Stream#allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) evaluates the [universal quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification) of the predicate over the elements of the stream and [`Stream#noneMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) evaluates the universal quantification of the negated predicate over the elements of the stream. The universal quantification always evaluates to `true` for an [empty set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification#The_empty_set).