# Understanding method reference with newly created instance

Tags: lambda, java-8, method-reference

I completely understand this form:

```
Set<T> set = new HashSet<>();
list.stream().allMatch(t -> set.add(t));
// And that
list.stream().allMatch(set::add);
```

But this ad-hoc instance really confuses me:

```
list.stream().allMatch(new HashSet<>()::add);
```

The most interesting is that hashset instantiated only one time.

Founded in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053487/how-to-check-if-exists-any-duplicate-in-java-8-streams)

Comment: See [“What is the equivalent lambda expression for System.out::println”](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28025717/2711488)

Comment: This is, by the way, similar to the question, how many arrays will be created when executing the statement `for(int i: new int[] { 1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 42 }) …`

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. But this in spec or just current impl details?

Comment: It is specified in [JLS§15.13.3. Run-Time Evaluation of Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3). At its end, there is a clarifying summary: “*When a method reference expression has an expression (rather than a type) preceding the :: separator, that subexpression is evaluated immediately. […] This means the expression preceding the :: separator is evaluated only when the program encounters the method reference expression, and is not re-evaluated on subsequent invocations on the functional interface type.*”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same as the first expression except that you don't keep a reference to the newly created set in your context. If you're not going to need the set's value after the `allMatch` invocation, it's the same. It's essentially a method reference expression with the newly created instance of `HashSet`. While it might be confusing at first sight, a `HashSet` is only created once, then the method reference bound to this newly created instance and used as such in the evaluation of the `allMatch` operation.

While it might be a working solution, it can be dangerous, especially with non-sequential (parallel) stream pipelines because it violates the `allMatch` predicate's [statelessness](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness) requirement in the API contract.