# How to check that List<String> doesn't contain duplicates ignore case

Tags: java, string, list, collections, duplicates

I want to check that `List<String>` doesn't contain duplicates **ignore case**

I understand that I can write construction like

```
for(...){
   for(...){} 
}
```

But I want to find nicer way

Comment: Convert it to a Set?

Comment: @The Head Rush Set uses usual equals, I need ignore case

Comment: Do you want to eliminate duplicates, identify them, or just know if there are any?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429860/easiest-way-to-convert-a-list-to-a-set-in-java

Comment: @bradimus i just want to know!

Comment: Maybe sort the list first using Collections.sort..... and then just keep on comparing list.get(i) to list.get(i+1)
If you are not interested in finding who is the duplicate then as already mentioned in the comments, convert to a set and compare the size to know if list had any duplicates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if exists any duplicate in Java 8 Streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053487/how-to-check-if-exists-any-duplicate-in-java-8-streams)

Comment: For big lists, I recommend my answer (below) which stops on first dup found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may create a `List` with only `String` in uppercase.
Then collect these elements into a `Set` that removes all duplicates.
At last, compare the size of the `Set` with the size of the `List` : if the size differs between, it means that you have a least one duplicate.

Executable code :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class RemoveDuplicateInsensitiveCaseString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<String> list =  Arrays.asList("abort", "Abort", "accent", "ACCENT");
      Set<String> set = list.stream().map(String::toUpperCase).collect(Collectors.toSet());     
      if (set.size() != list.size()){
        // you have duplicate
        System.out.println(set);
      }
    }
}
```

Output :

> [ACCENT, ABORT]

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for your answe

Comment: You could also implement a distinct stream like explained in this q/a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property

Comment: Why not collect directly to a set using `Collectors.toSet()`?

Comment: @Henrik No good reason : the habit to use frequently  `Collectors.toList()`. I forgot it. Thanks a lot. I updated.

Comment: @gstackoverflow You are welcome. I updated with a straighter implementation. Thanks to Henrik for the remark.

Answer (score 4):

Add the input list to a `TreeSet` with a case-insensitive comparator, and check the size afterwards:

```
List<String> input = Arrays.asList("a", "A", "b");

Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
set.addAll(input);

boolean containsDuplicates = input.size() != set.size();
```

Update: [Run it here](https://repl.it/LCia).

Comment: Short and simple, our use [Roee Gavirel answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46199128/4391450) for big list, no need to check the complet list if we found one duplicate.

Comment: @Henrik comparator detects order and doesn't affect equals. thus comparable which return 0 will be in set

Comment: @gstackoverflow : No, it's also used for equality checks in the set. Run the code to verify.

Comment: @gstackoverflow: Link added to a runnable version of the program. Play around with it.

Comment: It contradicts https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E)

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> origList;
Set<String> exists = new HashSet();

boolean dup = false;
for (String s : origList) {
    if (!exists.add(s.toLower()) {
        dup = true;
        break;
    }
}

// dup param will have your answer
```

Comment: Just saying, but using  [`Set.add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E)) would be enough, it return `true` if it was not present. so `if( ! exists.add(s.toLower()) return true;`

Comment: I like this solution, it will stop on the first duplicate, way more effective !