# What is the use of "System.out::println" in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I saw a code in java 8 to iterate a collection.

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
numbers.forEach(System.out::println);
```

What is the functionality of `System.out::println` ? And how the above code can iterate through the List.

And what is the use of the operator `::` , Where else we can use this operator ?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

It's called a *"method reference"* and it's a syntactic sugar for expressions like this:

```
numbers.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

Here, you don't actually *need* the name `x` in order to invoke `println` for each of the elements. That's where the method reference is helpful - the `::` operator denotes you will be invoking the `println` method with a parameter, which name you don't specify explicitly:

```
numbers.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: so what are other use of the `::` operator ?

Comment: what do you mean with *other use*?

Comment: I mean where else it can be used ?

Comment: It's used only for method references.

Comment: That lambda expression is [not exactly equivalent to the method reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28025717/2711488)

Comment: How will I use X as variable to pass to other method

Comment: commenting quite late but what is the REAL advantage ? is this not making the code less readable and less maintainable ?

Comment: So in other words, **method references are syntatic sugar for lambda expressions**. Is that correct?

Comment: @Holger absolutely .  To add more to that, one can refer Joshua Bloch speech https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7qXfoZIqi2Q at timeline 17:20.  This comes under bound type method reference.