# java.lang.NullPointerException is thrown using a method-reference but not a lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, nullpointerexception, java-8, method-reference

I've noticed something weird about unhandled exceptions using Java 8 method reference. This is my code, using the lambda expression `() -> s.toLowerCase()`:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testNPE(null);
    }

    private static void testNPE(String s) {
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> s.toLowerCase());
//        Thread t = new Thread(s::toLowerCase);
        t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler((t1, e) -> System.out.println("Exception!"));
        t.start();
    }
}
```

It prints "Exception", so it works fine. But when I change `Thread t` to use a method-reference (even IntelliJ suggests that):

```
Thread t = new Thread(s::toLowerCase);
```

the exception is not being caught:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.testNPE(Test.java:9)
    at Test.main(Test.java:4)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: I've checked in Eclipse my self and it works fine. Ideone.com throws NPE too

Comment: Check this out : https://ideone.com/nPvWex

Comment: lambdas are evaluated when executed, function references are evaluated when declared.

Comment: @njzk2 short and simple, thanks. Although it technically makes sense, it is very sneaky

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This behaviour relies on a subtle difference between the evaluation process of method-references and lambda expressions.

From the JLS [Run-Time Evaluation of Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3):

> First, if the method reference expression begins with an ExpressionName or a Primary, this subexpression is evaluated. **If the subexpression evaluates to `null`, a `NullPointerException` is raised, and the method reference expression completes abruptly**.

With the following code:

```
Thread t = new Thread(s::toLowerCase); // <-- s is null, NullPointerException thrown here
t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler((t1, e) -> System.out.println("Exception!"));
```

the expression `s` is evaluated to `null` and an exception is thrown exactly when that method-reference is evaluated. However, at that time, no exception handler was attached, since this code would be executed after.

This doesn't happen in the case of a lambda expression, because the lambda will be evaluated without its body being executed. From [Run-Time Evaluation of Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.4):

> Evaluation of a lambda expression is distinct from execution of the lambda body.

```
Thread t = new Thread(() -> s.toLowerCase());
t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler((t1, e) -> System.out.println("Exception!"));
```

Even if `s` is `null`, the lambda expression will be correctly created. Then the exception handler will be attached, the thread will start, throwing an exception, that will be caught by the handler.

---

As a side-note, it seems Eclipse Mars.2 has a small bug regarding this: even with the method-reference, it invokes the exception handler. Eclipse isn't throwing a `NullPointerException` at `s::toLowerCase` when it should, thus deferring the exception later on, when the exception handler was added.

Comment: A more theoretical way to reading this is: expressions are evaluated to "normal forms" (i.e. values). It so happens that *lambdas'* normal forms do *not* evaluate the body until called (also known as weak head normal form WHNF). This means that the value "error" is different from "() -> error" because the latter produces the error only when calling the function. This trick is also used to write fixpoint combinators in eager languages: you take the lazy combinator `fix f = f (fix f)` and add a lambda abstraction to introduce lazyness `fix f = x -> f (fix f) x`.

Comment: See also [“What is the equivalent lambda expression for `System.out::println`”](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28025717/2711488)

Comment: Not only does the exception occur before the uncaught-exception handler is set, the exception happens in the main thread instead of `t`.

Comment: "This doesn't happen in the case of a lambda expression, because the lambda will be evaluated without its body being executed." This part suggests that method reference evaluation is contrary to lambda expression evaluation and that method reference evaluation invokes referenced method. Method reference evaluation just have that additional step of veryfing subexpression, but that verification is not part of invocation, but it's part of an evaluation. From JLS: "Evaluation of a method reference expression is distinct from invocation of the method itself.". Anyway, great post.

Comment: Wow, just had this case in some code... I find it really strange... It is logical that a method reference is validated, but then you get a npe when declaring the method reference even though at that moment you have no idea if the method will even be executed: `Thread t = new Thread(s::toLowerCase); if(s!= null) t.start();` seems valid, and it's just awkward that it is not equivalent to `Thread t = new Thread(() -> s.toLowerCase()); if(s!= null) t.start();`. However, the JLS is specific, but one has to know...

Comment: @Martin the behavior is the same as with `someObject.new InnerClass()`. On a semantic level, when you say `list.iterator()`, it also doesn’t matter whether you’ll ever use the iterator, it will fail immediately when `list` is `null`. This applies to all kind of *bindings*. Whereas `() -> s.toLowerCase()` doesn’t bind `s`, it will reevaluate it every time the function is evaluated. In other words, `x -> System.out.println(x)` doesn’t bind `System.out`, but reevaluates it every time, reflecting when someone called `System.setOut` in the meanwhile. In contrast to `System.out::println`.

Answer (score 7):

Wow. You have uncovered something interesting. Let us take a look at the following:

```
Function<String, String> stringStringFunction = String::toLowerCase;
```

This returns us a function which accepts on parameter of type `String` and returns another `String`, which is a lowercase of the input parameter. This is somewhat equivalent to the `s.toLowerCase()`, where `s` is the input parameter.

```
stringStringFunction(param) === param.toLowerCase()
```

Next

```
Function<Locale, String> localeStringFunction = s::toLowerCase;
```

is a function from `Locale` to `String`. This is equivalent to `s.toLowerCase(Locale)` method invocation. It works, under the hood, on 2 parameters: one is `s` and another is some locale. If `s` is `null`, then this function creation throws a `NullPointerException`.

```
localeStringFunction(locale) === s.toLowerCase(locale)
```

Next is

```
Runnable r = () -> s.toLowerCase()
```

Which is an implementation of `Runnable` interface which, when executed, will call method `toLowerCase` on given string `s`.

So in your case

```
Thread t = new Thread(s::toLowerCase);
```

tries to create a new `Thread` passing the result of the invocation of `s::toLowerCase` to it. But this throws a `NPE` at once. Even before thread is started. And so `NPE` is thrown in your current thread, not from inside thread `t`. This is why your exception handler is not executed.

Comment: “the result of the invocation of `s::toLowerCase`” needs a clarification. The creation of the function instance is not an invocation.