# Creating a method reference on a null-reference does not throw an exception

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, null, java-8

Is there a reason why it is possible to create method references on a 
`null` reference in Java? Doing this is probably never correct but can result in errors which are hard to find later:

```
public class Test {
    void m() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = null;
        Runnable fn = test::m; // no exception
        System.out.println(fn); // prints Test$$Lambda$1/791452441@1c20c684
        fn.run(); // throws a null pointer exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing with Eclipse? I tested with JDK 1.8.0_51 and it throws the NPE where expected. This probably answers the question then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413106/thread-setuncaughtexceptionhandler-and-java-8-method-reference/. Because it should throw an NPE at `Runnable fn = test::m`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about behavior that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Tunaki yes I tested in Eclipse and it does not throw an exception when I uncomment the last line

Comment: @Michael Yes, it seems there is a bug in Eclipse regarding this (same as the linked question).

Comment: Problem still exists in Eclipse Neon

Comment: *Wow* it's painful when your tools mislead you like that.

Comment: It makes a kind of sense, since for this type of method reference, the left side of the :: is an expression that returns a reference. While this is more explicitly a null reference, this would have the same effect: `functionThatReturnsNull()::method`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a reason why it is possible to create method references on a  `null` reference in Java?

**It isn't**, but apparently there's a bug in Eclipse in this regard (edit: which has since [been fixed](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=521182)). According to the specification, and when you use the JDK's tools, it fails with an NPE on the `Runnable fn = test::m;` line.

Proof: http://ideone.com/APWXna (or compile and run it locally with `javac` and `java` rather than Eclipse)

Theory: From [JLS §15.13.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3):

> First, if the method reference expression begins with an *ExpressionName* or a *Primary*, this subexpression is evaluated. **If the subexpression evaluates to `null`, a `NullPointerException` is raised**, and the method reference expression completes abruptly.

*(My emphasis.)*

Comment: Was this bug reported to Eclipse?

Comment: @DidierL: I've no idea, I don't use Eclipse.

Comment: As a workaround: Lambda, or static method reference does not throw in the evaluation phase, if you want to use nullable object's method anyway. [Runnable fn = () -> test.m()] or [Consumer<Test > c2 = Test ::m]