# Runtime evaluation of expressions in Java method references

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, method-reference

In section [Run-Time Evaluation of Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3) of the Java Language Specification, it is mentioned that:

> At run time, evaluation of a method reference expression is similar to evaluation of a class instance creation expression, insofar as normal completion produces a reference to an object. Evaluation of a method reference expression is distinct from invocation of the method itself.
>
> First, if the method reference expression begins with an *ExpressionName* or a *Primary*, this subexpression is evaluated. **If the subexpression evaluates to `null`, a `NullPointerException` is raised, and the method reference expression completes abruptly. If the subexpression completes abruptly, the method reference expression completes abruptly for the same reason.**

And *ExpressionName* and *Primary* are defined in the [method reference expression syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13):

> ```
> MethodReference:
> ```
>
> > ```
> >   ExpressionName :: [TypeArguments] Identifier
> >   ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments] Identifier
> >   Primary :: [TypeArguments] Identifier
> >   super :: [TypeArguments] Identifier
> >   TypeName . super :: [TypeArguments] Identifier
> >   ClassType :: [TypeArguments] new
> >   ArrayType :: new
> > ```

I was interested by the highlighted part and wanted to test the mentioned behavior using the below code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Testing...");
        final Person p = null;
        foo(p::getName); // I was expecting an NPE here
    }

    private static void foo(Supplier<String> supplier) {
        System.out.println(supplier);

        // supplier.get();  // uncommenting this causes an NPE, but not when evaluating
                            // the method reference, but rather when the method is invoked.
    }

    static class Person {
        String getName() {
            return "x";
        }
    }
}
```

However, the line `foo(p::getName)` does not throw a NullPointerException. Am I misunderstanding the above quote from the JLS? If yes, could someone explain more the meaning of the above quote or give an example where it would occur?

Comment: interesting, I would have expecting it to throw the exception indeed and I tried changing it to a lambda expression (thinking this for sure will break), but it did not. good question

Comment: I agree, according to the spec, the `p::getName` method reference should have thrown the NPE. Guess they didn't add that validation, so the NPE is deferred until actually used. See related [JDK-8131323](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8131323).

Comment: There is an [earlier question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37681625/2711488), however, no link to a report in the Eclipse bug tracker there. I’m quiet sure, I have seen one in the past…

Comment: @Holger excellent find - then this is a duplicate I guess

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=521182

Comment: @Holger I was just about to create a new bug :) Thanks for the helpful link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh darn! That's an [eclipse bug (`ECJ`)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=521182), it fails with `javac/java` (I've tried 9 here in the example, but same thing happens in 8):

```
 Testing...
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:221)
 at org.eugene.so.DeleteMe.main(DeleteMe.java:11)
```

Comment: According to [JDK-8131323](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8131323), you no longer get NPE with jdk 8 b119, even though bug is closed as "Not an Issue", given the spec calls for NPE.

Comment: @Andreas: “b119” refers to “beta 119” (note the date of that comment). While I don’t have beta 119 at hand, I can assert you that the specified behavior of throwing an NPE is shown by later versions, especially all release versions; the earliest version I have here for testing is b132. It’s not clear, which setup the commenter used, but the comment has been added when the issue was already closed.

Comment: @Holger DOH! Was think `u119` when I saw that `b119`.