# Duplicate with HashSet using method reference

Tags: lambda, java-8, hashset

I want to know if my `List<T>` has duplicates elements.

I have seen the method below :

```
public static <T> boolean areAllUnique(List<T> list){
    return list.stream().allMatch(new HashSet<>()::add);
}
```

It works and I'm surprised why ? Because it seems a new HashSet<> is created everytime (so basically the method should always return true even if duplicates)

If I write differently the method above, it no longer works :

```
public static <T> boolean areAllUnique(List<T> list){
    return list.stream().allMatch(t -> {
        return new HashSet<>().add(t);
    });
}
```

I'm surprised the 1st method works while the other does not. Because for me they look the same

Comment: See [What is the equivalent lambda expression for System.out::println](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28023364/2711488)…

Comment: Also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37413106/2711488)

Comment: might be obvious,  but `new HashSet<>(list).size() == list.size()` will work also.

Comment: @Eugene yes, but it’s not short-circuiting.

Comment: @Holger I have realized that right after I posted; thought about deleting or not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`new HashSet<>()::add` is a method reference referencing a specific instance of a `HashSet`.

It's equivalent to creating an instance of a `HashSet` outside that method, storing a reference to it in a variable `set`, and using the method reference `set::add` instead. i.e. it will always operate on the same `HashSet` instance.

The lambda expression behaves differently, since the body of the lambda expression is executed each time `allMatch()` has to apply the `Predicate` to an element of the `Stream`. And each time the body is executed, a new `HashSet` instance is created.