Why Optional lambda replace with method reference Causing NullPointerException
There is a A Class
class A {
    private String str;

    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }
}




this method works fine;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = null;
        Optional.ofNullable((String) null)
                .ifPresent(str -> a.setStr(str));
    }



This method Causing NullPointerException

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = null;
        Optional.ofNullable((String) null)
                .ifPresent(a::setStr);
    }


Why?
Those two methods should be no difference in my perspective;
How this happend?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413106/java-lang-nullpointerexception-is-thrown-using-a-method-reference-but-not-a-lamb this answers your question.
