# Java 8 stream unique Integers

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Can i reduce the following code to one/two line?

```
DTO dto;
List<DTO> dtos;
List<Integer> list1 = dtos.stream().map(DTO::getFirstId).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> list2 = dtos.stream().map(DTO::getSecondId).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Integer> reducedId = list1.stream().filter(list2::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Possible, probably. I'm not sure that you should though, unless you want to trade readability for a single line of code. Which you shouldn't.

Answer (score 10):

Using a single Java 8 stream is not a great choice here.
Instead you should first create a Set so that you can perform an efficient contains test.

```
Set<Integer> secondIds = dtos.stream().map(DTO::getSecondId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
List<Integer> reducedIds = dtos.stream().map(DTO::getFirstId).distinct()
        .filter(secondIds::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

You may force it into one stream operation, but the performance would be even worse than what you have now, i.e. an operation with quadratic time complexity.

A better approach would be:

```
Set<Integer> set = dtos.stream().map(DTO::getSecondId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
List<Integer> result = dtos.stream().map(DTO::getFirstId)
    .distinct().filter(set::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
// result now contains the common IDs
```

By collecting the second IDs into a `Set` instead of a `List`, you don’t need to use `distinct()` in the first stream operation and avoid the linear search applied to every element in the second stream operation when `contains` is invoked.

You may generally consider using a `Set` for remembering unique IDs. When using a `Set` as result type, you may avoid the `distinct()` of the second stream operation too:

```
Set<Integer> set = dtos.stream().map(DTO::getSecondId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
Set<Integer> result = dtos.stream().map(DTO::getFirstId)
    .filter(set::contains).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

If you suspect lots of duplicate IDs and want to keep the behavior of sorting out duplicates before checking the other `Set`, you may use:

```
Set<Integer> set = dtos.stream().map(DTO::getSecondId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
Set<Integer> result = dtos.stream().map(DTO::getFirstId)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
result.retainAll(set);
```

Note that if you prefer long, hard too read “one liner”, you can inline the `set` variable in all variants.

Answer (score 3):

If you're open to using a third-party library, you have a few options using [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/).  If you want to use `Stream`, the following should work using `Collectors2`.

```
MutableList<Integer> result =
    dtos.stream().map(DTO::getFirstId).collect(Collectors2.toSet())
        .intersect(dtos.stream().map(DTO::getSecondId).collect(Collectors2.toSet()))
        .toList();
```

Eclipse Collections also has its only `LazyIterable` type that can be used instead of `Stream`.

```
LazyIterable<DTO> iterable = LazyIterate.adapt(dtos);
MutableList<Integer> result =
    iterable.collect(DTO::getFirstId).toSet()
        .intersect(iterable.collect(DTO::getSecondId).toSet())
        .toList();
```

Finally, if you have large numbers of ids, you might want to use primitive sets to avoid boxing `Integer` objects.  You can either work with `Stream` and `Collectors2` again as follows:

```
IntSet second = dtos.stream().collect(
    Collectors2.collectInt(DTO::getSecondId, IntSets.mutable::empty));
IntList result = dtos.stream().collect(
    Collectors2.collectInt(DTO::getFirstId, IntSets.mutable::empty))
        .select(second::contains).toList();
```

Or you can use `LazyIterable` as follows:

```
LazyIterable<DTO> iterable = LazyIterate.adapt(dtos);
IntList result =
    iterable.collectInt(DTO::getFirstId).toSet()
        .select(iterable.collectInt(DTO::getSecondId).toSet()::contains)
        .toList();
```

Note: I am a committer for [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/).

Answer (score 2):

With [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex):

```
Set<Integer> set = StreamEx.of(dtos).map(DTO::getSecondId).toSet();
List<Integer> result = StreamEx.of(dtos).map(DTO::getFirstId)
                                        .filter(set::contains).distinct().toList();
```

Or by [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

```
Set<Integer> set = Stream.of(dtos).map(DTO::getSecondId).toSet();
List<Integer> result = Stream.of(dtos).map(DTO::getFirstId)
                                        .filter(set::contains).distinct().toList();

// OR:

List<Integer> result = Stream.of(dtos).map(DTO::getFirstId)
       .intersection(Stream.of(dtos).map(DTO::getSecondId).toSet()).toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do something like

```
List<Integer> reducedId = dtos.stream().map(DTO::getFirstId).distinct().filter(
    (dtos.stream().map(DTO::getSecondId).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()))::contains
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Not tested in my local, but it seems reasonable to me :)

Comment: you're right Patrick, I think your solution it's the best possible one.

Comment: @Patrick Parker: no, the second IDs are not rebuilt every time. When replacing the inner `Collectors.toList()` with `Collectors.toSet()`, it will do exactly the same as your solution, just less readable. When you have a method reference of the form `expression::name`, the expression will be evaluated only once and the result captured for the function, see also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28025717/2711488), just like with `for(Type var: expression) …`, the `expression` will only be evaluated once, not in every iteration

Comment: @Holger ah, good catch. I just glanced quickly and saw a stream() within a stream(). This answer is a bit cleverer than I first imagined. thanks

Comment: @Holger: It does. the second Ids will be rebuilt every time. it's can be verified by adding peek: ...dtos.stream().map(DTO::getSecondId).distinct().peek(System.out::println)...

Comment: @user3380739: maybe you have a different understanding of “every time”.

Comment: @Holger: I think we are on same page: "every time"  = "every iteration". please refer to below sample: the second code is much faster the first one:

    final List<Integer> list1 = IntList.range(0, 10000).toList();
    IntList.range(1, 1000).toList().stream().filter((list1.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet()))::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());

    final Set<Integer> set = list1.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
    IntList.range(1, 1000).toList().stream().filter(set::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: @user3380739: interesting, so you don’t suggest to use `peek` anymore, but to repeat your flawed “benchmark”? Just swap the order of the two…

Comment: @user3380739: by the way, `IntList.range(1, 1000).toList().stream()` doesn’t look like an advantage over `IntStream.range(1, 1000).boxed()` to me. Rather like a case of 3rd-party-library overdose…

Comment: @Holger, peek is the very first/simple step to verify it. 'benchmark' is a double confirmation. I has the utility class to do it in one line in two seconds. :-): 
final List<Integer> list1 = IntList.range(1, 100000).toList();

    Profiler.run(3, 1000, 3,
            () -> IntList.range(1, 1000).toList().stream().filter((list1.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet()))::contains).collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .printResult();

Comment: @user3380739: `peek` alone is sufficient to prove that method references work as specified, for `expression::name`, the expression is evaluated only once. If you experience other results, you have a broken compiler.

Comment: @Holger: interesting... I misunderstood your previous comments. i thought it's rebuilt every time after verified it by peek in my test and that's why i ran the benchmark. After checked your code and verified my test again.you're right. the answer is no. but i'm stuck on the benchmark test: Take a look test: http://ideone.com/5KAh6A. the second solution is at least 5 times faster than the first one on my laptop. but i can't figure out why. (BTW, i know the benchmark test is not good. but i don't think it matters for this discussion)

Comment: @user3380739: on Ideone, it prints zero two times as assertion are disabled by default. Besides that, [I already wrote “just swap the order of the two”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440189/java-8-stream-unique-integers/42440427?noredirect=1#comment72037954_42440427), as it is not unusual for this kind of “benchmark”, that the second operations runs faster than the first. There are several Q&As explaining the issue on [SO].