# Using instance method in java 8 :: method reference with null Object

Tags: java, java-8

Why when using an instance method in method reference (`::`) does not throw a `NullPointerException` if we set the Object instance to null?

```
  public class MethodReferenceTest {

        public static void main(String...strings){

            PredicateSample predicateSample = new PredicateSample();
            Predicate<String> predicate = predicateSample::isNotEmpty;
            // NullpointerException ???
            predicateSample = null;
            Arrays.asList("a","b","c",null)
                .stream()
                .filter(predicate)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
        }

        static class PredicateSample{
            public boolean isNotEmpty(String s){
                return ((s!=null) && (!s.isEmpty()));
            }
        }
    }
```

It seems like `predicateSample` is not invoked after constructing the Predicate?

Comment: You're setting the variable `predicateSample` to `null`. Why do you think there should be a NPE?

Comment: Internally java is not using this reference to invoke the instance method??

Comment: reference to your old predicateSample (before it was null) is already stored in predicate

Comment: During the method reference creation the object reference is resolved. And the created lambda expression is pointing to the `PredicateSample` object. Then you set the variable to `null` which is an independent operation.

Comment: See also [What is the equivalent lambda expression for System.out::println](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28025717/2711488)…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key line in [the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3) is where it is discussing the runtime evaluation of method references (emphasis mine):

> - If the form is ExpressionName :: [TypeArguments] Identifier or Primary :: [TypeArguments] Identifier ...
>
>   - ....
>   - The target reference is the value of ExpressionName or Primary, as determined **when the method reference expression was evaluated**.

So it doesn't matter if you change the value of the target reference afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

The method reference "remembered" the state of the `predicateSample` when it was initialized. It has a reference exactly to that `new PredicateSample()` you have created before.

After 2 lines executed, you have got two references to that `new PredicateSample()` - the `predicateSample` and the one "within" the method reference.

Changing the former makes no effect to the latter.

---

Let's do an interesting trick.

Here is an array to wrap up a `new PredicateSample()` into a `predicates[0]`:

```
PredicateSample[] predicates = new PredicateSample[1];
predicates[0] = new PredicateSample();
```

Within the lambda, you use a reference to the `predicates[0]`;

```
Predicate<String> predicate = string -> predicates[0].isNotEmpty(string);
```

You update the `predicates[0]` to `null` and do the same stuff:

```
predicates[0] = null;
Stream.of("a","b","c").filter(predicate).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PredicateSample predicateSample = new PredicateSample();
Predicate<String> predicate = predicateSample::isNotEmpty; //it will work fine and initializing with false.
            // NullpointerException ???
predicateSample = null;
Arrays.asList("a","b","c",null).stream().filter(predicate).forEach(System.out::println);
```

in above code you are initializing `predicateSample` with `null` and thereafter there is no use of this object `predicateSample`.

in your code you have write

```
Predicate<String> predicate = predicateSample::isNotEmpty;
            // NullpointerException ???
predicateSample = null; // null initialize after `isNotEmpty` call. then why Null Pointer will raised ?
```

now no use of `predicateSample` further. then why NPE?

> Modified code to throw NPE.

```
PredicateSample predicateSample = new PredicateSample()
// NullpointerException ???
    predicateSample = null;;
    Predicate<String> predicate = predicateSample::isNotEmpty; //it will not work fine and raise NPE.
              Arrays.asList("a","b","c",null).stream().filter(predicate).forEach(System.out::println);
```