# Lambda capturing vs non capturing

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

Can you please explain why the first lambda is capturing and the second not.

```
   Runnable createLambdaWithCapture() {
      return System.out::println;
   }    
   Runnable createLambdaWithApparentCapture() {
        return () -> System.out.println();
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I thought that a method reference is "synthetic sugar" for a lambda. Even intellij idea suggests to replace this method reference with the same non capturing lambda.

Comment: See also [What is the equivalent lambda expression for System.out::println](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28023364/2711488)

Comment: @Holger, nice explanation. Wonder why they dont dig into details in almost every book on lambdas. they just say you can replace a lamdba with a method reference, and don't say there can be some pitfalls.

Comment: Well, the main purpose of these books is to simplify, as otherwise, anyone would just read the Java Language Specification instead. But it’s a hard decision, where to draw the line. Unfortunately, there are lots of documents, especially web pages, which seem to be sloppy because their author just doesn’t know it better. You know, everyone can set up a web page…

Answer (score 8):

The first snippet is capturing because it evaluates `System.out` when the `return` statement is executed and *captures* the corresponding object reference to be used within its `Runnable#run` implementation.

The second snippet generates a `Runnable` instance that is not capturing because `System.out` is only evaluated once that instance's `run` method is invoked. It could have changed since the time the `return` statement was executed.

Answer (score 3):

In the first method, `System.out` is evaluated immediately in the return statement.

The equivalent lambda would be as if you factored `System.out` out to a variable which then becomes an effectively final closure:

```
Runnable createLambdaWithCapture() {
    PrintWriter foo = System.out;
    return () -> foo.println(); // foo is captured and effectively final
}
```

In the second method, System.out (which is a static field) is not final and could be changed later at runtime. It is not invoked until `Runnable::run` is invoked.

```
System.out = aPrintStream;
Runnable runnable1 = createLambdaWithCapture();
Runnable runnable2 = createLambdaWithApparentCapture();
System.out = anotherPrintStream;
runnable1.run(); // prints to aPrintStream
runnable2.run(); // prints to anotherPrintStream
```

Comment: The equivalent lambda would be `PrintWriter foo = Objects.requireNonNull(System.out); return () -> foo.println();`

Comment: @Holger that might be technically true, and relevant to the other question you answered, but it doesn't seem significant to this question and just becomes noise.

Comment: Speaking of irrelevant but technically true things, [`System.out` *is* `final`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out), though it can still change. But you have to call [`System.setOut(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut-java.io.PrintStream-) to change it. This oddity is one of Java’s historical legacies.