# Why my java lambda expression cannot work while its imperative style works properly?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, apache-spark-sql, jvm

I have years experience of Java 8 and its lambda. But I met a insane problem when I developed a hello-world-size Spark program.

Here I have a Java class, in which the Data annotation is from Lombok:

```java
@Data
public class Person implements Serializable {
  private String name;
  private Long age;
}
```

And then I built a java list containing objects of `Persion` class:

```java
        Person p1 = new Person("sb", 1L);
        Person p2 = new Person("sth", null);
        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>(2);
        list.add(p1);
        list.add(p2);
```

so good so far. And then I tried to generate a Spark Dataset using the list:

```java
SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().master("local[1]").appName("SparkSqlApp").getOrCreate();
Encoder<Person> personEncoder = Encoders.bean(Person.class);
Dataset<Person> dataset1 = session.createDataset(list, personEncoder);
dataset1.foreach(new ForeachFunction<Person>() { // 1
            @Override
            public void call(Person person) throws Exception {
                System.out.println(person);
            }
});
dataset1.foreach((ForeachFunction<Person>) System.out::println); //2
```

Notice that, the block 1 is equivalent to block 2 in java and the block 2 is simplified from block 1 by IntelliJ IDEA. The only difference is block 2 is using lambda expression.

However, when I execute the program, block 1 ends well while block 2 run in exception:
[image]

What the... big earth and big universe? Why the JVM or Spark engine does things like this?!

Comment: This is interesting. I usually see the opposite behavior -- block 1 fails, but block 2 succeeds. The problem regardless is that the function is being defined as an object which refers to the outer class. That is, the class which contains the code that got the session and built the dataset is the outer class. It's not serializable, nor should it be.

Comment: By the way, have you tried with a newer Java version? Perhaps the compiler is a bit "smarter" now and doesn't create an unnecessary reference to the outer class.

Comment: Yes guys it comes with the `capture` thing. I read the generated code by adding VM argument `-Djdk.internal.lambda.dumpProxyClasses`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in [What is the equivalent lambda expression for System.out::println](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28023364/2711488), the method reference `System.out::println` is not identical to the lambda expression `x -> System.out.println(x)`.

The method reference *captures* the current value of `System.out`, to invoke `println` on it each time the function is invoked, rather than evaluating `System.out` again each time as the lambda expression’s body does.

As also said, this rarely makes a difference, but here, it does. When you try to serialize the function, it will try to serialize all captured values, including the `PrintStream` instance read from `System.out` during the instantiation. The `PrintStream` is not serializable and it would be quite challenging to implement a serializable `PrintStream` fulfilling the expectations.

But it’s important to keep in mind that when you serialize the lambda expression `x -> System.out.println(x)` or an equivalent class object and deserialize it in a different environment, the `System.out` it will read there will evaluate to a different `PrintStream` than in your original environment. This doesn’t matter when the distributed computing framework takes care to pipe everything printed to the standard output back to the originator.

But it’s important to keep in mind that `static` fields which are not part of the serialized data may have different contents in different environments in general.

Comment: Sounds like it occurs only with `System.out`？And I replace it with Log framework and bang! It succeeded. `ForeachFunction<String> functionBody = log::info;`

Comment: Depends on the logging framework. It will work if `log` is serializable.

Comment: It seems does not relate with the framework. I use `java.util.logging.Logger` which is not serializable.

Comment: Not for the standard setup: https://ideone.com/F5lQZF “NotSerializableException: java.util.logging.Logger”. However, in a specific environment, a log manager may return a subclass of `Logger` with serialization (or RMI) support, further, the framework could use an extended serialization which can handle loggers in a special way.

Answer (score 1):

The interface [ForeachFunction](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/ForeachFunction.html) extends `Serializable`. `Dataset.foreach(f)` may be serializing the argument `f`. In the following test, `testBlock1` succeeds and `testBlcok2` fails (NotSerializableException). But I don't know why.

```java
public class AAA implements Serializable {

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface ForeachFunction<T> extends Serializable {
        void call(T t) throws Exception;
    }

    @Test
    public void testBlock1() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        ForeachFunction<String> functionBody = new ForeachFunction<String>() {
            public void call(String t) throws Exception {
                System.out.println(t);
            }
        };
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("data/block1.obj");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)) {
            oos.writeObject(functionBody);  // success
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testBlock2() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        ForeachFunction<String> functionBody = System.out::println;
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("data/block2.obj");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)) {
            oos.writeObject(functionBody);  // fail (NotSerializableException)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested your cases and indeed, event `functionBody = t -> System.out.println(t)` would be  successful. So the problem source I suppose is method reference. You gave me a huge hand.

Comment: If the test class `AAA` does not implement `Serializable` in my code, `testBlock1` will also fail. The `functionBody` in `testBlock1` is an anonymous inner class of the test class `AAA` and should be serialized with an instance of the class `AAA` that encloses it. However, the `functionBody` in `testBlock2` is not an inner class of class `AAA` and does not seem to implement `Serializable` in substance.